# Can't validate user by query on database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

My code is not running.it always print **$errmassage="username or password incorrect";**.  may be my query is not perfect.but i tried many time to count **num_rows**.but not working.please anybody help me.

```
$search= "SELECT * from registermember WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$search);
    $checkrow=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($checkrow > 0) {
        $cookie=setcookie("$username",md5('$password'), date()+7200,"/");
        $_SESSION['user']=$username;
        header("location:mainpage.php");
    }
    else{
        $errmassage="username or password incorrect";
    }
```

Comment: have you included your connection?

Comment: please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your pages and let us know if any error is thrown. And `print_r($_POST);` (if username / password are posted) would be useful too

Comment: On top of that, use of MD5... it's so unsafe !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do

```
echo $search;
die;
```

And test the query on phpMyAdmin or another. Be sure the problem is code or SQL.

Comment: thank you so much.problem is in SQL.two of my varriable was interacting.Now this is okk.